# Paypal NVP SOAP (classic api), Everything looks fine, but no arrive money

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-nvp

so I would like to make a simple NVP SOAP api express checkout integration in my system (php). I used the general old php paypal class ( DPayPal() ).

So the sandbox and the live account also redirect fine to the expresscheckout page (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=), and at here I can pay with a sandbox and live account also, and the paypal redirect to me the Success site.

The problem is: the money not arrive the live account (also not arrive in the sanbox account either), and didnt take the money from my credit card or paypal account either. But I can send money to this business live account from my paypal account.

DPayPal settings in class file:

```
protected $apiVersion = "74.0"; //Set PayPal API version
//If you are using live environment use the following URL: https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp 
//If you are using sandbox environment then use the following URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
protected $payPalAPIUrl = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
protected $errorReportingEnabled = true;
protected $errors = array(); //Here you can find errors for your last API call 
protected $lastServerResponse; //Here you can find PayPal response for your last successfull API call
protected $curl;
```

My account is ok i guess, but not really know... but for example after login paypal Still show the setup intructions: (It's time to start getting paid!Finish setting up so you can open for business.)

- API NVP SOAP credentials, checked
- Accept PayPal payments from all your online stores, YES ACCEPT ALL, checked
- Email address comfirmed,
- Linked bank account, checked
- Linked credit card, checked
- comfirmed business name, checked
- limit lifted to unlimited,

Thanks everyone!

regards, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment after buyers approves the payment?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

Please note that NVP is deprecated. Please consider upgrade to REST.