# Payment declined, please check with your bank or use a different card

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, oscommerce

After checkout user goes to PayPal and then returns to the website with the following message:
**Payment declined, please retry or use a different card**
My client uses the osCommerce CMS, and they integrated PayPal Direct for online payments.

Any suggestions? Like should we upgrade a code or there is may be some other issues?

Answer (score -1):

Declines are a normal part of processing cards. You can log the API response, which might have a bit more information on the reason, but generally it is as it says: that card was declined, the user can try again preferably with a different one.

osCommerce and its modules tend to be very old, there are better ways to integrate nowadays such as Braintree or [Advanced Credit and Debit Cards](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/), but a newer integration is better for unrelated technical/security reasons; declines can and will happen regardless, they are a business issue.

Comment: But integration is currently set in sandbox mode then why this error occurs? So I have tried a lot of test card but still faces the same error.

Comment: Impossible to advise without seeing the API response. For PayPal they should be testing with a random card from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/creditCardGenerator . There are also a newer static card list that can work for PayPal in sandbox: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/sandbox/card-testing/ , but it's always better to try with a random one.

Comment: The client is using NVP API  which is now deprected may be this cause declined issue, I just found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429190/paypal-nvp-soap-classic-api-everything-looks-fine-but-no-arrive-money